# supressing the page footer in crystal report leaves a blank space

Tags: crystal-reports

i'm using crystal report to generate a report that have a page footer which should only appear in the last page of the report if the report has more then one page.
I used the conditional suppressing by the formula PageNumber < TotalPageCount and checked the "suppress blank section" this does shows the footer only in the last page but leaves the space that the footer occupies as blank in all the others pages, is there a way to remove that blank space.
pls help

Comment: How about using the report footer instead of page footer?

Comment: @heringer i tried that and also tried inserting a second page footer and conditionally supress it but it dosen't seem to solve the issue i still have blank space when the footer is supressed.